# JavaScript regular expression literal persists between function calls

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this piece of code:

```
function func1(text) {

    var pattern = /([\s\S]*?)(\<\?(?:attrib |if |else-if |else|end-if|search |for |end-for)[\s\S]*?\?\>)/g;

    var result;
    while (result = pattern.exec(text)) {
        if (some condition) {
            throw new Error('failed');
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

This works, unless the throw statement is executed. In that case, the next time I call the function, the exec() call starts where it left off, even though I am supplying it with a new value of 'text'.

I can fix it by writing

var pattern = new RegExp('.....');

instead, but I don't understand why the first version is failing. How is the regular expression persisting between function calls? (This is happening in the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome.)

**Edit** Complete test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test Page</title>
<style type='text/css'>
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#log p {
    margin:     0;
    padding:    0;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function func1(text, count) {

    var pattern = /(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight)/g;

    log("func1");
    var result;
    while (result = pattern.exec(text)) {
        log("result[0] = " + result[0] + ", pattern.index = " + pattern.index);
        if (--count <= 0) {
            throw "Error";
        }
    }
}

function go() {
    try { func1("one two three four five six seven eight", 3); } catch (e) { }
    try { func1("one two three four five six seven eight", 2); } catch (e) { }
    try { func1("one two three four five six seven eight", 99); } catch (e) { }
    try { func1("one two three four five six seven eight", 2); } catch (e) { }
}

function log(msg) {
    var log = document.getElementById('log');
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = msg;
    log.appendChild(p);
}

</script>
</head>
<body><div>
<input type='button' id='btnGo' value='Go' onclick='go();'>
<hr>
<div id='log'></div>
</div></body>
</html>
```

The regular expression continues with 'four' as of the second call on FF and Chrome, not on IE7 or Opera.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of posting a complete, simplified test case, hope you don't mind. I've seen this behavior as well and wondered why it would be. It looks and smells like a bug, but then, sometimes things are very subtle, and it's surprising that both FF and Chrome would have it given their *completely* different underlying Javascript engines.

Comment: Just to be clear, it works as long as the error/exception isn't thrown, but if 'some condition' becomes true and the exception is thrown, then the function will fail on the next invocation because the pattern continues from where the exception was thrown? That sure sounds like a bug that's out of your hands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RegExp objects that are created by means of a regex literal are cached, but `new RegExp` always creates a new object.  The cached objects also save their state, but the rules governing that aspect are apparently not very clear.  Steve Levithan talks about that in [this blog post](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/fixing-javascript-regexp) (near the bottom).

Comment: The blog says it will be fixed in Firefox 3.7 (and I'm on 3.6.3). I think I'll just stop using RE literals though, as a cross-browser solution to this behaviour.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Note that "...are cached..." should be "...*were* cached by some implementations as of ECMAScript 3rd edition..." followed by the statement that they may no longer be cached as of the latest spec (thankfully!).

Comment: @Charles: If you stop using literals, you're in for a world of hurt with escaping rules. :-) Just reset `lastIndex` before use (unless you also muck about with other flags after instantiation). And be glad that the latest spec fixed this little silliness.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go out on a limb here: I think the behavior you're seeing is a bug in FF's and Chrome's Javascript engines (heresy!). Surprising that it should happen in two such different engines, though. Looks like an optimization error. Specifically, section 7.8.5 of [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) says:

> A regular expression literal is an input element that is converted to a RegExp object (see 15.10) each time the literal is evaluated.

The only wiggle room I see is in the phrase "..each time the literal *is evaluated*" (my emphasis). But I don't see why the resulting object should be magically retained any more than any other object literal, such as:

```
function func1() {
    var x = {};
    return x;
}
```

There, subsequent calls to `func1` will give you *distinct* objects. Hence my saying it looks like a bug to me.

**Update** Alan Moore [points to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645273/javascript-regular-expression-literal-persists-between-function-calls/2645450#2645450) an [article by Steve Levithan](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/fixing-javascript-regexp) in which Levithan makes the claim that the ECMAScript 3rd edition specification *may have* allowed this kind of caching. Fortunately, it is not allowed as of ECMAScript 5th edition (the spec I was working from) and is, therefore, going to be a bug Real Soon Now. Thanks Alan!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer, but I will hazard a guess:

The literal expression which is the pattern has global scope, and is evaluated (into a RegExp object) only once, whereas if you use `new Regexp` its argument is still global, but is just a string, not a RegExp.

Comment: @Colin: Except it *doesn't* have global scope, any more than the object in `var x = {};` has global scope. That's also a literal, but you'll get different objects on each function invocation.