# Why do two regex literals in my Javascript vary on a property?

Tags: javascript

I read in *Javascript: The Good Parts* by Douglas Crockford that javascript regular expression literals share the same object. If so, then how come these two regex literals vary in the `lastIndex` property?

```
var a = /a/g;
var b = /a/g;

a.lastIndex = 3;
document.write(b.lastIndex);​
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gTR2/)

0 is outputted as opposed to 3.

Comment: that would be new to me. Do you have some other sources where it claims that? Or could you perhaps quote the part of the book that seems to be contradicting the behaviour?

Comment: Your answer is described in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645273/javascript-regular-expression-literal-persists-between-function-calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section 7.8.5 of the [ECMAScript Documentation](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) makes it quite clear they are two different objects:

> **7.8.5 Regular Expression Literals**
>   A regular expression literal is an input element that is converted to a RegExp object (see 15.10) each time the literal is evaluated. Two regular expression literals in a program evaluate to regular expression objects that never compare as === to each other even if the two literals' contents are identical. A RegExp object may also be created at runtime by new RegExp (see 15.10.4) or calling the RegExp constructor as a function (15.10.3).

Answer (score 0):

Because they are different objects.

```
document.write(a === b);
```

Even this outputs `false`.

Either Crockford was wrong, or he was right at the time but times have changed.

I realize this isn't a particularly helpful or informative answer; I'm just pushing back on what I perceive as your disbelief that something Crockford wrote could be (now) false.

Do you have a reference to that claim, by the way? Would be interesting to read it in context (I don't have the book).

Comment: Check the link davidgoli posted. It is just a misunderstanding of what Crockford actually meant.